# mTLS for nodejs server and axios client. Self signed certs not accepted

Tags: node.js, axios, mtls

I am trying to setup mTLS between my nodejs/express client and my nodejs server.  The client is using axios as the https client.  Here are the steps I followed:

// create the required certs, keys, csrs

```
# create server ca
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server-ca-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key server-ca-key.dev.pem -out server-ca-cert.dev.pem -subj "/CN=*.college.net"

# create server certs
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -key server-key.dev.pem -out server-csr.dev.pem -subj "/CN=*.college.net"
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.dev.pem -CA server-ca-cert.dev.pem -CAkey server-ca-key.dev.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.dev.pem

# create client ca
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out client-ca-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key client-ca-key.dev.pem -out client-ca-cert.dev.pem -subj "/CN=*.college.net"

# create client certs
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out client-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -key client-key.dev.pem -out client-csr.dev.pem -subj "/CN=*.college.net"
openssl x509 -req -in client-csr.dev.pem -CA client-ca-cert.dev.pem -CAkey client-ca-key.dev.pem -CAcreateserial -out client-cert.dev.pem
```

In my client code using nodejs and axios I have:

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

 // Load your client certificate and key
  const clientCert = fs.readFileSync(`./client-cert.dev.pem`);
  const clientKey = fs.readFileSync(`./client-key.dev.pem`);

  // Create an agent with the client certificate and key
  const agent = new https.Agent({
    cert: clientCert,
    key: clientKey,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(`./server-ca-cert.dev.pem`)],
  });

  try {
    const myConfig = {
      url: `/${route}/${action}`,
      method: "post",
      baseURL: `https://someurl`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      httpsAgent: agent,
      responseType: "text",
      data: {
        stuff
      },
    };

    const response = await axios(myConfig);
```

The nodejs server uses this code:

```
// setup https server
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(`./server-key.dev.pem`), // Path to your server private key
  cert: fs.readFileSync(`./server-cert.dev.pem`), // Path to your server certificate
  ca: [fs.readFileSync(`./client-ca-cert.dev.pem`)], // Path to your client certificate
  requestCert: true, // Request client certificate
  rejectUnauthorized: true, // Reject connections without valid client certificate
};

const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(process.env.USERAPI_port, () => {});
```

The error I am getting is that the request is rejected due to self signed cert. I don't want to set rejectUnauthorized to false, as I want to confirm the identity of the connecting client. I don't understand why and I am still trying figure out how to observe the requests so I can see what is going on.

Comment: do I need a separate CA for the client and server, I would think I could use the same one?

Comment: You've created CA and EE (server and client) certs with different keys but the same name `/CN=*.college.net`. That doesn't work. **The CA and EE(s) MUST have different names.** If they have the same name the EE cert _appears_ self-signed and can't be verified corectly. And yes you can use one CA for both server and client (and even other things like email) if you prefer -- but only within your own systems, or people who trust you a _lot_ (e.g. family)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as shown in the comment, the solution is in the naming.  So here is the updated way of creating the certs.

```
# create ca
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -subj "/CN=Root CA"

# ---------------- Development -------------------------------
# create server certs
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -key server-key.dev.pem -out server-csr.dev.pem -subj "/CN=*.college.net"
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.dev.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.dev.pem

# create client certs
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out client-key.dev.pem
openssl req -new -key client-key.dev.pem -out client-csr.dev.pem -subj "/CN=website"
openssl x509 -req -in client-csr.dev.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out client-cert.dev.pem
```

The same CA was used to create the client and server certs.  Other than some file name changes, the javascript code is correct.